# Understanding mongodb find query more

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongoose, database

Just a quick question in relation to the following mongodb query:

```
var queryParams = {
        $or: [
            {'stats.created_by': userId},
            {'user_list.user_id': userId},
            {'invite_list.user_id': userId},
            {'invite_list.email': userEmail}
        ],
        deleted: false
    };
```

This query is given to a ItemModel.find(queryParams); - Im trying to understand the table scan impact here? My understanding is that it will do a full scan based on the deleted attribute and then filter on $or clause.

Ok, I ran the following explain and all items were scanned with an index on deleted.

```
db.items.find({$or: [
            {'stats.created_by': '559cd76338e42c533a83b8a7'},
            {'user_list.user_id': '559cd76338e42c533a83b8a7'},
            {'invite_list.user_id': '559cd76338e42c533a83b8a7'},
            {'invite_list.email': 'some@something.com'}
        ],
        deleted: false}).explain();
```

Can I make any improvements here?

Thanks.

J

Comment: You could have used the time spent on asking this question on examining `explain()` output instead.

Answer (score 1):

db.getCollection('items').createIndex({ deleted: 1 }); speeds up the query and also ignores the $or since this is just a filter on the result set. Might look at making the query more restrictive.